# Substitude father class from child class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a class `Father` and an inherited class `Child`. Inside the Child's  constructor I want to pass a `Father` class to cast all Father's properties.

This is my code

```
class Father
{
    int prop1;
    int prop2;
    // many more properties;
}

class Child : Father
{
    string _name;
    int _age;
    //etc...

    public Child(string Name, int Age, Father father)
    {
        this._name = Name;
        this._age = Age;
        base = father; //<== this is what I mean to do
    }
```

I know I can't do this directly. What is the right way?

This is complete code, some code is in spanish

```
class AuditRegistry : Audit
{
    protected string _cud;
    protected int _employee, _consecutive;
    protected DateTime _date;
    public string CUD { get { return _cud; } }
    private int Consecutive { get { return _consecutive; } }
    public DateTime Date { get { return _date; } }
    public int Client { get; set; }
    public int Employee { get { return _employee; } }
    public float NetAmount
    {
        get
        {
            float acum = 0;
            //Sum (qty * price) of products in a struct collection

        }

    }
    public float GrossAmount
    {
        get
        {
            float acum = 0;
            //Sum in acum (qty * price + tax) of each products in a struct collection
            return acum;
        }
    }
    public float Paid
    {
        get
        {
            float acum = 0;
            //Sum every paid in a struct collection

            return acum;
        }
    }
    public float Change
    {  get; set;        }
    public bool FullPaid
    {
        get { return (Paid != null && Paid >= NetAmount); }
    }
    public ArticlesCollection Products { get; set; } //struct previusly declared
    public PaidsCollection Paids { get; set; } // struct previously declared

    public AuditRegistry(string CUD, int Employee, int Consecutive, DateTime Date, int Client, int C, int Company, int Terminal )
    {
        this._cud = CUD;
        this._employee = Employee;
        this._consecutive = Consecutive;
        this._date = Date;
        this.Client = Client;
        base._c = C;
        base._company = Company;
        base._terminal = Terminal;
    }
}

class Order : AuditRegistry
{
    int _consec;
    public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public int Consecutive { get { return _consec; } }
    public char Modification { get; set; }
    public string Code { get { return (_consec.ToString() + Modificacion); } }
    public bool Entregado { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor for load a Order from database to memory
    /// </summary>
    public Order(DateTime DeliveryDate, int Consecutive, char Modification, AuditRegistry Registry) // Here is the child constructor
    {
        this.DeliveryDate = DeliveryDate;
        this._consec = Consecutive;
        this.Modification = Modification;
        base = AuditRegistry; //Wrong idea
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor for new Order
    /// </summary>
    public Pedido(DateTime DeliveryDate, int Employee)
    {
        this.DeliveryDate = DeliveryDate;
        this._consec = 1;
        this.Modification = 'A';
        base._employee = Employee;
        base._date = DateTime.Now;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semantics of a child being a father aside...

A good way is using a copy constructor:

```
class Father
{
    int prop1;
    int prop2;
    // much more properties;
    protected Father(Father copy)
    {
        prop1 = copy.prop1;
        prop2 = copy.prop2;
    }
}
class Child : Father
{
 string _name;
 int _age;
 //etc...
 public Child(string Name, int Age, Father father)
    : base(father)
 {
    this._name = Name;
    this._age = Age;
 }
}
```

Its a protected constructor so only children of the parent class can call it. You use the constructor chaining `base(father)` to intantiate the construtor of the base class and pass the object you want to copy.

You can't assign the `base` object directly in code, its just a reference to the instance of the base class that the current class derives from.

Comment: A deep copy is pretty rare in C#. Make sure you understand what you are doing with this solution.

Comment: That's a interesting answer, in any way, can't avoid enumerating and matching properties?

Comment: As you said in your answer, it would make a lot more sense if Father was renamed "Person". Its not clear if it was just a poor example in the question or what is going on.

Comment: @CesarRomeroo depends, you could make the constructor of Child take all the properties that you want to copy over and in the Father class have the fields or properties settable (protected or public), there are a number of ways to do it, unfortunately `base = something` is not one of them.

Comment: I see, actually all variables of the `Father` could be accessed by the `Child`, so this will be the same if in the `Child` Constructor copy over the properties, just wondering the were another way to override completely the `Father` class, i'm suppose I have to change a little bit the class structure as @BradleyDotNET say's

Answer (score 2):

There is *absolutely* no way to do this. A `Child` *is* a `Father` and you can't just swap part of the object out to another reference. The `base` keyword is only intended for calling base class methods explicitly.

Given that a `Child` is **not** a "type of" `Father`, inheritance is probably the wrong answer here anyways. You would be better off doing something like:

```
class Person
class Father : Person
class Child : Person
{
    Father father;
}
```

(Pseudo-code above). Basically, prefer composition over inheritance here.

Comment: @CesarRomeroo You'll need to show a few more details, such as what properties need to be shared.

Comment: @CesarRomeroo Bradley believes that, because of the code example currently in your post, there is no need for the inheritance you currently have. If you have better names for the classes you are actually working with it would be really helpful to make a small example in your post. That would help to flush out if you need inheritance or not.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I posted the real code, much of them is in spanish I hope don't cause any problem

Comment: @CesarRomeroo Any translation you have would be awesome, its very hard to read as is.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I finish the translate, hope work better

Comment: @CesarRomeroo Thank you. Could you clarify if `Order` really is a "type of" `AuditRegistry`?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You make me doubt, I figure out that an `Order`generates a registry in the `Audit` just for being a sell movement, in that way have the same properties or `AuditRegistry` but adding the new ones specifics from an order

Comment: @CesarRomeroo It sounds like the above answer would be reasonable then, though it still sounds like a decent case for composition instead of inheritance

Comment: @BradleyDotNET what could be a example of composition having this scenario?

Comment: @CesarRomeroo For example, an `Order` simply *holds* an associated `AuditRegistry`. Composition is for "has a" relationships (and allows the assignment you want). Inheritance is for "Is a type of" relationships.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I know in any way the result can be done, but wish would redude/simplify the loading, managing and saving the objects

Comment: @CesarRomeroo Which is why you usually favor composition over inheritance. Unless it really is an "is a type of" relationship, (and polymorphism usually applies at that point) just use composition.

Comment: @CesarRomeroo If you are still confused, please find me in the C# chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I'm sure "is a type of" as you mention i'm concidering polymorphism in that way applys the answer of Ron

Comment: @CesarRomeroo Without showing any virtual methods you can't be using polymorphism. That said, its fine to use inheritance, I'm just worried you don't understand when to do so and when not to.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET That's right, you can see my code would you do it in other way?

Comment: @CesarRomeroo Seeing your code, nothing seems to require inheritance.  Since this comment thread is getting quite long, please find me in the above chat room if you are still confused/concerned.